# cannot submit spark application to docker compose

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I'm trying to submit a small spark application to a spark cluster on docker-compose. However, it always fails. Here is my spark cluster on docker-compose (I've already had some Kafka broker just ignore it):

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOSTNAME=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
      - PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python3
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
      - "6066:6066"
      - "7077:7077"
      - "8080:8080"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1" # Adjust as needed
          memory: 1g  # Adjust as needed
    # command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY = 3g
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES = 2
      - PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python3
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2" # Adjust as needed
          memory: 4G  # Adjust as needed
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-2:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY = 3g
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES = 2
      - PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python3
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2" # Adjust as needed
          memory: 4G  # Adjust as needed
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    networks:
      - spark-network

  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.9
    container_name: zookeeper-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka1:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5
    container_name: broker-1
    hostname: broker-1
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9093,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper 

  kafka2:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5
    container_name: broker-2
    hostname: broker-2
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9094,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka3:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5
    container_name: broker-3
    hostname: broker-3
    ports:
      - "9095:9095"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9095,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9095,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper  
  
networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and my simple spark app:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("My App") \
   .master("spark://172.28.240.1:7077") \
   .getOrCreate()

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 100))

print("THE SUM IS HERE: ", rdd.sum())
# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

When I submit, it raises error:

```
23/12/08 01:44:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.20.0.2 executor 0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 20 more

23/12/08 01:44:54 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IT4931-bigdata-Movie-processing\test_submit.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("THE SUM IS HERE: ", rdd.sum())
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2291, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2044, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (172.20.0.2 executor 0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 20 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 20 more
```

I'm just a beginner in spark. I've tried to fix it all day and still have errors. Can sb help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to Spark not being able to find the Python executable (`C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe`). This might be due to the fact that the path is specific to a Windows environment, but your Spark cluster is running in a Dockerized Linux environment.

1. Update the Python path in your Spark application, and also use `127.0.0.1` instead of `spark-master`:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("My App") \
   .master("spark://127.0.0.1:7077") \
   .config("spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON", "/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python3") \
   .getOrCreate()
```

2. Submit the Spark application using spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 spark_app.py
```

3. Monitor the Spark application using web UI that is available at http://localhost:8080

Comment: I tried and still got that error. If I submit to cluster on my local machine, it works fine. But it doesn't work with cluster on docker-compose.